# Using Regular expression, how to find two digits great than a number in a string in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string at most 1000 length, in the string every two digits represent a number, how can I find if the string contains a number that is great than my input number?

e.g. 000102252500 represents numbers 00, 01, 02, 25, 25, 00,
if I have an input number at 20(this number can be changed), how can I find if the string contains a number great than 20 using regular expression?

Thanks!

Comment: This really doesn't sound like a problem well suited for Regular Expressions. Is this a class assignment, and if so, are you specifically required to use regex to solve this?

Comment: Thanks Bob, I was thinking split the string into arrays, then compare each item with the input, but just want to know if Reg expression can solve this kind of issue.

Comment: Agreed - regular expressions are for string matching but it is difficult to do mathematical operations (like numerical comparisons) with them, and I would avoid doing so unless absolutely required. You end up passing if the first digit is 0 or 1, matching on 3 to 9, and then, if it's a 2, examine the second digit to make sure it's not a 0. It's just ugly.

Comment: ... not to mention that, given that the input number can change, OP would need a fairly well thought out RegEx generator that would work for any value between zero and 99. Either that or 100 hard coded regexes.

Comment: Ewww, I hadn't noticed that. Yeah, if 20 isn't even a fixed threshold, I wouldn't even try it with regex.

Answer (score 1):

With this regular expression you should match it
but you must generate a regular expression to match all 2 digit numbers bigger than the input number in this case 20 which is inside the middle parenthesis.
(2[1-9])|([3-9][0-9]) //This matches any number from 21 to 99

```
    ^(\d\d)*((2[1-9])|([3-9][0-9]))(\d\d)*$
```